# Consulta SQL con JOIN y una condicion de actualización

Tags: sql, nodejs, express, condiciones, mysql-workbench

mi consulta es si es posible que con SQL se pueda actualizar una tabla mediante una condición IF o CASE, lo intententé hacer ocn backend con NODEJS pero tampoco se me ocurrió como hacerlo.
Les explico un poco y luego muestro como es la consulta. Tengo 3 tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por un lado los Usuarios realizan sus pronosticos, y por otro lado el Administrador carga los resultados reales de cada fecha disputada. Todo ésta información se une en la tabla Pronostico.
***Mi consulta es, como puedo hacer para que, segun lo pronosticado sea el puntaje obtenido?
Por ejemplo, si "Pedro" dijo que ganaba el Local y acertó obtenga 10pts de puntaje y sino 0.***

EDITO PARA QUE SE PUEDA OBSERVAR LO QUE SE HIZO DEL LADO DEL BACKEND PERO LA TABLA CON EL PUNTAJE SOLO SERÁ VISTA EN EL FRONTEND, ESOS DATOS NO SE ME REFLEJAN EN LA BD OBVIAMENTE

```js
app.get('/datosADMIN', function (peticion, respuesta) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    const consulta = `
    SELECT
    usuarios.Nombre,
    fechas.NumFecha,
    fechas.Local,
    fechas.Visitante,
    pronostico.Pronostico,
    fechas.Resultado,
    pronostico.Puntaje
    FROM prueba_db_jugadores.fechas
    INNER JOIN prueba_db_jugadores.pronostico
    ON fk_idFechas = idFechas
    INNER JOIN prueba_db_jugadores.usuarios
    ON fk_idUsuarios = idUsuarios
    where fechas.resultado is not null;
    `
    connection.query(consulta, function(error, filas, campos){
      let obj = filas
      let arr = Object.entries(obj)

      arr.forEach(element => {     
        if(element[1].Resultado == element[1].Pronostico){
            element[1].Puntaje = 10
        }else{
            element[1].Puntaje = 0} 
        return element
    });
   
    respuesta.render('datosADMIN', {datos: arr});  
  
    }); 

    connection.release()
    }) 
})
```

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Numero de Fecha</th>
            <th>Local</th>
            <th>Visitante</th>
            <th>Pronostico</th>
            <th>Resultado</th>
            <th>Puntaje</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% datos.forEach(datos =>     { %>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].Nombre %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].NumFecha%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].Local %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].Visitante %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].Pronostico %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].Resultado %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= datos[1].Puntaje %>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <% }) %>
        </tbody>
      </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Generalmente hablando, la lógica de negocios no reside en la base de datos. Tu aplicación debería tomar esa decisión. La base de datos únicamente se encarga de guardar esa información.

Comment: Sisi eso lo entiendo, por eso es mi consulta si es posible. De no ser posible, como puedo hacer para que mi aplicación realice ésa logica y que me devuelva los datos hacia la BD. Intenté hacerlo de una manera pero solo logré que lo muestre en el Frontend pero no sé como volver a capturar esos datos y llevarlos a la BD

Comment: Es posible? Todo es posible. _Como puedo hacer para que mi aplicación realice esa lógica?_ Qué has intentado? Cuál es el código en el front end? Cuál es el código en el back end? cuál es el código que utilizas para guardar? Qué datos le estás enviando? A menos que edites la pregunta y agregues el código, lo único que puedo decir: `const puntaje = pedroAcerto ? 10 : 0;`.

Comment: Editado para mejor comprensión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es curioso que ya tengas una columna llamada puntaje y no tenga el dato que pides. Si se actualiza correctamente, no tendrías que calcularlo al vuelo. Por otro lado, el cálculo que pides es bastante sencillo, considerando que el valor de pronóstico tenga que ser igual al valor de resultado, solo tienes que usar un `CASE`.

```
SELECT
    usuarios.Nombre,
    fechas.NumFecha,
    fechas.Local,
    fechas.Visitante,
    pronostico.Pronostico,
    fechas.Resultado,
    pronostico.Puntaje,
    CASE WHEN pronostico.Pronostico = fechas.Resultado THEN 10 ELSE 0 END AS PuntajeCalculado
FROM prueba_db_jugadores.fechas
INNER JOIN prueba_db_jugadores.pronostico
ON fk_idFechas = idFechas
INNER JOIN prueba_db_jugadores.usuarios
ON fk_idUsuarios = idUsuarios
where fechas.resultado is not null;
```

Comment: Eso mismo estoy consultando, de eso se trata... No se como utilizar o como realizar el CASE, para mi no es sencillo disculpen la ignorancia. Por otro lado, la columna Puntaje fue solo para realizar una prueba cargando datos y realizando el if en el backend.